# JNI jni/cyberlevel9.c:17:31: error: request for member 'NewDirectByteBuffer' in something not a structure or union

Tags: android, c++, c, eclipse, java-native-interface

Eclipse gives me this error when I try to build:

```
jni/cyberlevel9.c:17:31: error: request for member 'NewDirectByteBuffer' in something  not a structure or union
jni/cyberlevel9.c:18:28: error: request for member 'NewGlobalRef' in something not a structure or union
```

This is the problem part of the code:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_cyberbg_natcamlevel9_NativeCameraLevel9Start_allocNativeBuffer(JNIEnv* env, jobject this, jlong size)
{
void* buffer = malloc(size);
jobject directBuffer = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(buffer, size);
jobject globalRef = env->NewGlobalRef(directBuffer);

return globalRef;
//return (NewDirectByteBuffer*)(*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer(buffer, size);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JNI calls from C program look like

```
(*env)->fun(env, p1, ...)
```

Your calling style is OK from C++, where a special wrapper class is defined in `jni.h`:

```
env->fun(p1, ...)
```

You can probably resolve your problems by simply renaming `jni/cybrrlevel9.c` to `jni/cyberlevel9.cpp`

Or,

```
jobject directBuffer = (*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer(env, buffer, size); 
jobject globalRef = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, directBuffer);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm new here and can't vote up still

Comment: I change it how you say but now there are new errors    jobject directBuffer = (*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer(buffer, size);
    jobject globalRef = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(directBuffer);

Comment: jni/cyberlevel9.c:17:5: warning: passing argument 2 of '(*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/cyberlevel9.c:17:5: note: expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'jlong'
jni/cyberlevel9.c:17:5: error: too few arguments to function '(*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer'
jni/cyberlevel9.c:18:5: error: too few arguments to function '(*env)->NewGlobalRef'

Comment: @user2551271 Since you are staying with C, add `env` as the first parameter of each JNI function, as the first example in the answer shows.

Comment: I put the code you can paste "as is" to the bottomof the answer

Comment: BTW, your native function makes very little sense. You can achieve exactly same effect if you allocate a direct byte buffer in Java.